# HCUP KID import into R

Tags: r, import, bigdata

I'm new to all of this:  programming, statistics, and R.  I am trying to load a large dataset into R.  It is in ASC format.  I've tried many hours everything from read.table, to rgdal, to read.asc with no success.  The file is 1.5 gb so I'm unable to open it in a text editor.  I got a tutor and he said it would need to be read in line by line.  The plan was to read in the first 50 records to see if it worked and it did not.  I've got all but a few empty columns.   Is there an obvious problem here?  I've checked all the column names and the character numbers, the working directory and file name is correct.

Here is a link to the record layout so you can see why it was done this way:  http://www.hcup-us.ahrq.gov/db/nation/kid/tools/stats/FileSpecifications_KID_2012_Core.TXT

```
input = file("KID2012Core.asc","r")
numRows = 50;

df = data.frame(row=seq(1,numRows),
HOSP_KID = NA,      
RECNUM = NA,           
AGE = NA,              
AGE_NEONATE = NA,  
AMONTH = NA, 
AWEEKEND = NA,      
DIED = NA,             
DISCWT = NA,            
DISPUNIFORM = NA,   
DQTR = NA,      
DRG = NA,              
DRG24 = NA,             
DRGVER = NA,         
DRG_NoPOA = NA,   
DX1 = NA,          
DX2 = NA,                
DX3 = NA,                
DX4 = NA,                
DX5 = NA,                
DX6 = NA,                
DX7 = NA,                
DX8 = NA,                
DX9 = NA,                
DX10 = NA,               
DX11 = NA,              
DX12 = NA,              
DX13 = NA,              
DX14 = NA,   
DX15 = NA,   
DX16 = NA,   
DX17 = NA,   
DX18 = NA,   
DX19 = NA,   
DX20 = NA,   
DX21 = NA,   
DX22 = NA,   
DX23 = NA,   
DX24 = NA,   
DX25 = NA,   
DXCCS1 = NA,
DXCCS2 = NA,
DXCCS3 = NA,
DXCCS4 = NA,
```

and so on for 142 columns

```
for(i in seq(1,numRows)) {
    line = readLines(input,n=1)


df$HOSP_KID[i] = substr(input, 1, 5) 
df$RECNUM[i] = substr(input, 6, 13)
df$AGE[i] = substr(input, 14, 16)            
df$AGE_NEONATE[i] = substr(input, 17, 18)              
df$AMONTH[i] = substr(input, 19, 20) 
df$AWEEKEND[i] = substr(input, 21, 22 )      
df$DIED[i] = substr(input, 23, 24)             
df$DISCWT[i] = substr(input, 25, 35)           
df$DISPUNIFORM[i] = substr(input, 36, 37)  
df$DQTR[i] = substr(input, 38, 39)      
df$DRG[i] = substr(input, 40, 42)           
df$DRG24[i] = substr(input, 43, 45)
df$DRGVER[i] = substr(input, 46, 47)        
df$DRG_NoPOA[i] = substr(input, 48, 50)  
df$DX1[i] = substr(input, 51, 55)          
df$DX2[i] = substr(input, 56, 60)                
df$DX3[i] = substr(input, 61, 65)                 
df$DX4[i] = substr(input, 66, 70)
```

and so on }

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're working with a fixed-width file, which are a bit of work to read. There is a base function for the purpose called `read.fwf`, but it does require you to count the widths of each column and spaces in between, which can get somewhat annoying.

The `readr` package offers several options for setting column specifications within its alternative, `read_fwf`. In this case, the information at the top sets you up well to use its `fwf_positions` helper function:

```
library(readr)

df <- read_fwf('http://www.hcup-us.ahrq.gov/db/nation/kid/tools/stats/FileSpecifications_KID_2012_Core.TXT', 
               fwf_positions(start = c(1, 5, 10, 27, 31, 61, 65, 69, 71, 76), 
                             end = c(3, 8, 25, 29, 59, 63, 67, 69, 74, NA)),    # use NA here for ragged column
               skip = 20)

df
## # A tibble: 142 × 10
##       X1    X2    X3    X4          X5    X6    X7    X8    X9
##    <chr> <int> <chr> <int>       <chr> <int> <int> <int> <chr>
## 1    KID  2012  Core     1    HOSP_KID     1     5    NA   Num
## 2    KID  2012  Core     2      RECNUM     6    13    NA   Num
## 3    KID  2012  Core     3         AGE    14    16    NA   Num
## 4    KID  2012  Core     4 AGE_NEONATE    17    18    NA   Num
## 5    KID  2012  Core     5      AMONTH    19    20    NA   Num
## 6    KID  2012  Core     6    AWEEKEND    21    22    NA   Num
## 7    KID  2012  Core     7        DIED    23    24    NA   Num
## 8    KID  2012  Core     8      DISCWT    25    35     7   Num
## 9    KID  2012  Core     9 DISPUNIFORM    36    37    NA   Num
## 10   KID  2012  Core    10        DQTR    38    39    NA   Num
## # ... with 132 more rows, and 1 more variables: X10 <chr>
```

This file is actually a codebook for another file, but you can use the positions in `X6` and `X7` to read it equivalently; probably something like

```
df2 <- read_fwf('a_big_fwf.txt',
                fwf_positions(start = df$X6, stop = df$X7, col_names = df$X5),
                n_max = 50)    # read first 50 lines
```

If you plan on reading the whole thing, you may want to specify `col_types` as well; the information is in `X9`, though you'll need to convert it to a format `readr` understands. For more information, see `vignette('column-types', package = 'readr')`.

Comment: Forgive me, total newb!  It looks like both of these are creating the dataframe...or is 'a_big_fwf.txt' where my KIDCORE2012.asc file should go to be read in?

Comment: Yep, that's where the path to the 1.5Gb one goes. You may need to tweak that one with `skip` or whatnot; it's hard to say without seeing the data.